# How to bound a footer to the page bottom with relative parent position?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'am using bootstrap to create a page layout. My footer bound to the page bottom as described [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/). This works fine.

But when I'am place a footer inside of container with relative position, I can't to bound footer to the page bottom. Here is example

```css
html,
body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.container{
  position:relative;
  min-height:100%;
  height:auto !important;
  height:100%;
}

header{
  height:120px;
  background-color:#eee; 
}

.middle{
  background-color:#aaa;  
}

footer{
  height:120px;
  background-color:#888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      Header
    </header>
    <div class="middle">
      Middle
    </div>
    <footer>
      Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to do it with only CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this css code to the footer

```
footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

this will position the footer at the bottom of the first parent with a relative position which is in this case the container div

Comment: When I add your CSS code, footer is bound page bottom (good!), but overflow header and middle, when page height is small

Comment: i didn't get your problem ...the footer will fallow the container ...if the container is small ...the footer will go up

Comment: I want to tell that .middle must have padding from the bottom as footer height. Now it's ok!

Comment: ah yes the padding-bottom should be equal to the footer's height to make sure the all content are visible